# CISCO Wireless roaming: best practices

Tags: cisco, wireless

We are deploying a Cisco wireless network with a Cisco WLC 2504 controller and 2602 AP's.
Can you tell about your recommendation to deploy good L2 wireless roaming? What about such features as 802.11k (wlan assited-roaming neighbor-list, wlan assited-roaming dual-list, wlan assited-roaming prediction), 802.11r (Fast Roaming) and CCX Location Mesurement.

I discovered that there are a lot of problems with 802.11r and clients that do not support this feature.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your are correct about 802.11r and it's issues with lack of client-support.

Assuming your deploying WPA2-Enterprise or similar (where session keys are established)...you should take a look at the following. It's great reading, especially since your inquiring about 'best practices' with very little detail on your deployment (ie target devices/applications...VoWiFi?):

802.11r/k: 
http://www.revolutionwifi.net/2013/05/apple-ios-fast-roaming-with-aerohive-wi.html

CCKM/PCK-OKC and description of roaming techniques: http://www.revolutionwifi.net/2012/02/wi-fi-roaming-analysis-part-2-roaming.html

Follow the links at the bottom of the 2nd URL for Cisco recommendations, but again...will depend heavily on your target device/application.